# DDD, external datas and Repository

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

I'm thinking to use DDD for our next application. I have already found a lot of interesting papers and answers but cannot find a solution to my problem :

We have an SOA. architecture where some services are known as master of their datas. That's nice but I can't figure how to use them nicely with DDD.

Given a service "employees" who is the master of the `Employee` datas, it is a crud over a couple of simple values (first and lastname, birthdate, address).
My new app, should track the trainings offered to those employees. So I have the concept of `Participant`, a `Participant` has the same values as an `Employee` plus a list of trainings and a skill.

We can suppose that the "trainings" applications has a database with a table of participants that contains a `participant_id`, `skill` and one `employee_id` used to retrieve the first and lastname.

Am I correct ?

But now, which component may I use to call the "employees" service ? Is it the `ParticipantRepository` so that when I get a participant I have is names. Or is it the application service who complete the `Participant` datas before using them. Or may I  explicitly call the employees service when needed ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In your training application (I mean in the domain of your application) the concept of an employee might not exist as other than an external reference. As you correctly said, that will be a Participant.

I understand that you need to get some data from the employee service to populate the participant. I can think of few options.

1) ParticipantRepository builds a Participant, which is an aggregate root, some of that data might be in a `PersonalDetails` value object. This value object is constructed by calling the employee app. This approach is easy, but might not be the best. This is the approach you mentioned, where the ParticipantRepository calls an interface `PersonalDetailsService` and the implementation of that interface does the actual call to the Employee service. In this way, your domain has no idea that is dealing with employees, as it only sees PersonalDetails.

2) Eventual consistency by replicating data from the employee service: If the employee service can send a notification when an employee is updated (e.g. via messaging) you can listen to those events and have a read only copy of the data. The benefit of this is that your app will work even if the employee service goes down. The problem is that you might need to build something to re-send data that might have got lost.

Both of these approaches are explained quite well in the book [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577)

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd probably go with 2) if the existing system allows it.